# Chrome custom tab opens as a new tab in chrome not inside the app why?

Tags: java, android, android-customtabs

How can I open my custom tab inside my app without opening Google Chrome in background...

this is my code

```
String a="http://www.gpamravati.ac.in/gpamravati";
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder=new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent custom=builder.build();
        custom.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        custom.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(a));
```

[image: when I click on website menu item it invokes the chrome custom tab]

[image: It opens like this]

Comment: will you share some code

Comment: check my code i posted

Comment: Try removing this line `custom.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");`

Comment: What android version are you using? Is Google Chrome still your default browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved my problem by adding:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Just add this code to your manifest under activity

Below is the output
[image: output]

Answer (score -1):

in short,
you should open a fragment OnNavigationItemSelectedListener and use the webview inside the opened fragment and open the Url.

**xml** for fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <WebView
         android:id="@+id/main_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**java** code for fragment

```
    public class UrlFragment extends Fragment  {

    private WebView mWebView;

    //inflate the layout

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_url, container, false);
    return v;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mWebView = (WebView) view(R.id.main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.gpamravati.ac.in/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

and that the basic code needed to open a URL in webview inside the fragment. Read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted)

Comment: but i want to use custom tab

Comment: few days before it work very well means custom tab opened inside the app rather then new tab in chrome but now what happens i dont know..!

Comment: okay got it then remove the package set in your code because this is what opening the url in chrome package.

Comment: i removed the package but same problem exists..!

Comment: Yes I uninstalled and installed the chrome with new version

Comment: If my problem arises by updating chrome in my phone But in emulator same problem occurs 
Without updating